# Installer built with install4j - Tab order on the License Agreement screen works partially

Tags: install4j

On the default License Agreement screen on the install4j-built installer, the tab order (navigating across buttons using TAB and Shift+TAB buttons) does not work correctly.
Although the tab order partially works (you can successfully navigate between "Back", "Next", "Cancel" buttons), once the user hits a couple of TAB keys after "Cancel", the control is lost and you have to use the mouse to get it back on track.
Also, by default, the focus is on the Agreement text box (or multi-line text panel) and there, the TAB order does not work at all.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, for me the tab order works fine. Please report bugs to support@ej-technologies.com, SO is not a suitable medium for this. Here we handle "How to" questions.

Comment: Ok, I will do so. Thanks a lot.